# why does adding a second full text index statement to START return 0 results in Neo 4j 2.0-m01

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This cypher query correctly returns > 0 results

```
START publishers=node:app_fulltext('Name:"Facebook"')
MATCH publishers-[:InstanceOf]-app
RETURN app.Title AS Title;
```

However if I add a second start statement that is a full text index search, it erronously  returns 0 results even though it's not being used in a match statment or anything.

```
START publishers=node:app_fulltext('Name:"Facebook"'),
descriptions=node:description_fulltext('Name:"Facebook"')   
MATCH publishers-[:InstanceOf]-app
RETURN app.Title AS Title;
```

Note that I can add a 2nd start clause that is not a full text index it will return the correct results.  My aim was to combine them into a union clause where I want to return apps who's publishers have the keyword in the description or the name.  I know that we should have both properties in the same index, which we will change in the future, but I'm curious about what the issue might be as it currently is.

Comment: Is there a node that matches the second index query?

Comment: Can you do this example in console.neo4j.org and post the link here to have a look?